# Add-PnPCustomAction custon action in list SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm using the Add-PnPCustomAction command but I can't add an actiom to a SharePointo list.
can you help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiAsG.png)

Answer (score 1):

Create SPFx extension to implement your custom ECB menu action.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-from-ecb-to-spfx-extensions

[As Custom JavaScript embedded via user custom actions are not supported currently.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries#overview-of-customization-options)

Then, you could deploy by [PnP PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpcustomaction?view=sharepoint-ps).

```
Add-PnPCustomAction -Title "title" -Name "name" -Location "EditControlBlock" -ClientSideComponentId SPFxcomponentid -ClientSideComponentProperties properties
```